# Differentiating between 收 and 受

Tags: usage

I've noticed a lot of people have trouble differentiating between 收 and 受.

Both their pronunciations and meanings are *similar*.

How to differentiate between the two?

What tricks and tips are there to remember when to use which? (Instead of the other.)

Comment: googled ＂ 受 收 ＂ ？This will bring up ２ websites discussing the issue， a ３rd requires registration。

Comment: Receive vs. accept?

Comment: My opinion is that 受 is used to describe a less specific situation, e.g. 受北方冷空气影响, while for 收, you can always picture as someone accepting things with their own hands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may see the definitions of these two characters on zdic.net (maybe you already know), an online dictionary which is convenient for looking up the characters.

As a native speaker, I think (subjectively) the main difference of these two characters is that 收 emphasizes the action of receiving, gathering or reducing, and 受 emphasizes the finish of receiving an action, which is something sort of similar to the perfect tense.

I guess that your doubt comes from distinguishing 接收 from 接受? In some sentenses these two words are almost the same, for example:

> 他接受了这份礼物。
>   他接收了这份礼物。

But I still feel that there is a tiny differece as I said above, 接收 puts more significance on the action of receiving.

Another differece may be that, 收 is usually used with "concrete" things like gift, data, signal, while 受 is usually used with abstract things like suggestion, training, offer, and only some "concrete" things.

Hope it helps.

**Reference**

收 on zdic.net
www.zdic.net/z/1a/js/6536.htm

受 on zdic.net
www.zdic.net/z/16/js/53D7.htm

Answer (score 5):

收 is an active action; 受 is a passive action.

Comment: Good one. Example: 我来收尸了 vs 我来受死了

Answer (score 5):

In addition to answers above, here is a tip if you don’t feel uncomfortable with homosexuality. In informal language 受 can be used as a noun meaning "bottom" in gay terms, as opposed to 攻("top").

So you can see that 受 is passive compared to 收, e.g., 受到攻击->be under attack, 受伤->be injured, 受挫->suffer a setback, 受骗->be deceived, 收获->harvest, 收养->adopt, 收购->purchase, 收银员->cashier (customers would be delighted if the cashier didn't ask them for money^_^). The two characters can be even combined to one word 收受 implying the subject is active and/or passive during the process (收受贿赂->demand, receive or agree to accept bribes).

I hope this will help and please forgive me for any mistakes in English.

---

Added at the request of Mr. Ho (14/12/20):

The usage of 攻/受 is borrowed from Japanese ACG(Anime, Comics & Games), where it's known as 攻め/受け or seme/uke (not sure the spelling is correct because I don’t know Japanese). Here are some explanations from Wikipedia:

> MPAA & 广电总局 WARNING:
>
> The web pages have been rated **Not-safe-for-work-and-do-Not-view-it-in-the-presence-of-your-children** for nudity and sexuality.

Seme and uke in Yaoi: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaoi#Top_and_bottom_or_seme_and_uke

Slang in Chinese gay culture:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homosexuality_in_China#Slang_in_contemporary_Chinese_gay_culture

A related widely used slang word 基友 (literally gay-friend) is worth mentioning. It denotes a close male friend of a guy regardless of his (or his friend's) sexual orientation, for example, 我要去参加一个基友的婚礼->I’m going to attend a good friend’s (the groom) wedding. However, some “genuine” gay men may consider the word offensive.

Comment: Do you have a citation for the top/bottom comment?

Comment: Hi @MarchHo, I have updated my answer. Sorry to keep you waiting.

Answer (score 2):

I think the difference between 收 and 受 is easier to see with examples.
In any case, it would be a mistake (and confusing) to consider them as the direct equivalent of the English "to receive".

**受 seems to be used for immaterial things** (such as feelings, influence, etc.) Its passive connotation really depends on the context or other words in the sentence/expression.

ex:

- 他很受欢迎。 - He is very popular.
- 他受到你的影响。- He is influenced by you. (which can be good or bad).

Even when the character 受 is used in words, it is for abstract things: 感受 (a feeling)

**收 seems to be used for material things** (a letter, a document, a SMS).

ex:

- 我收到你的短信。 - I received your SMS.
- 别忘记收垃圾。- Don't forget to collect the trash.

Same things here, when 收 is used in words, it describes material things: 收音机 - Radio (set). Literally *the device receiving sounds*.

Of course their might be other differences and details, but I think this is the big picture.

I hope this answer your question. I wish you pleasure and success in your studies!

Answer (score 0):

收 is collecting, 受 is receiving

Comment: Hi Luke, thank you for your contribution! It would be better if you add more information with reference :D

Answer (score 0):

[收](https://tw.dictionary.yahoo.com/dictionary?p=%E6%94%B6):
1. to accept; to receive
2. to gather; to collect
3. to put away
4. to retrieve; to get back
5. to conclude; to finish

[受](https://tw.dictionary.yahoo.com/dictionary?p=%E5%8F%97):
1. to receive; to accept 
2. an indicator for the passive voice
3. to bear; to endure
4. to be subjected to

From the above, this confirms that to 受 is a passive action.

To PJ Hades' example above, I would add to it with additional takes on the translation, that:
他接受了这份礼物。  --> He accepted the gift. He's taking it! It belongs to him now!

他接收了这份礼物。  --> He received the gift. As in, he physically collected or was handed the gift from someone else.

Answer (score -2):

收 ： Accept， ask for 
受： be given

This shop accepts cash only.
This award is given to the hero.

Comment: You are talking about 授 not 受